# Alternative Single Page Application routing mechanism without hash or regex

Tags: javascript, url, routes, url-routing, single-page-application

I’m working on my own SPA (Single Page Application) stack tool. I’m currently thinking about router mechanism - I have doubts if I should go with hash (#) based router, or think about something else:

1. Use `window.history` API - twitter already do some small SPA helper: Implementing pushState for twitter.com (https://blog.twitter.com/2012/implementing-pushstate-for-twittercom) - don’t really know why other popular (React, Angular) framework routers don’t use it and rely on hash mechanism?
2. Use hash implementation, but to improve url mapping speed (and implementation) use only one level of nesting routes + params, e.g.:

   - `#/posts`,
   - `#/post-new/`,
   - `#/post/<post-id>`,
   - `#/post-edit/<post-id>`,
   - `#/post-comments/<post-id>`

etc.

So no complex regex, after first slash there will be always only one, very descriptive route slug, and after second slash will be a param (or params such as`?param1=X&param2=Y` etc.). Any flaws of such (2nd point) approach?

EDIT:

Due to repeating answers - no, I don't want to use existing solutions (angular/react/ember etc.) - I want to implement it by myself (I want to build tool for myself, not struggle with existing API that just doesn't fit to me)

Comment: Can you use angular or you want to develop your own routing?

Comment: _but to improve url mapping speed_ Any reason to believe that is going to be a problem in the first place?

Comment: no, I don't want to use angular (I've updated question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

The only two possibilities for a good frontend routing are using the [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) or the default hash implementation.

**Long answer**

You could use [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and remove the `#` from the URLs telling to angular to use the history api ([tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)):

```
angular.module('test', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  }]);
```

and maybe you will need in your `<head>`:

```
<base href="/">
```

With `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` you actually tell angular to use the history api.

"Don’t really know why other popular (React, Angular) framework routers don’t use it and rely on hash mechanism?" Because IE9 and previous doesn't support the history api as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history).

An example of an angular app where there is no `#` so `html5Mode` is enabled is [Google Font](https://fonts.google.com/)

Comment: there's also a big server-side diff between hashes and real urls, you can't just "switch" to history api without "real" urls being there, unless you use a slow hacky 404 handler to route.

Comment: @paolo.basso99 thank You for explanation (especially about lack of IE support and `html5mode`)